# expression: deque iterator not incrementable (special case - i can't figure it out)

Tags: c++, stl, assert, undefined-behavior

I have something like `deq.push_back(object)` which works fine in a source file but not in another one - if I try the same operation there I get the runtime error in the title. How can it be possible? `deq` is a global variable in the source file where the code works. Just as a test, I tried to swap the global declaration and the extern between the source files and I get the same result, the second source file triggers the runtime error. What am I missing here? Why I can't use push_back from there?

Comment: Please post a minimal (!!!) example that reproduces the error, otherwise we cannot help you. The code fragment you have posted should work, provided the object `deq` is of type `deque<T>` where `T` is a type that `object` can be converted to.

Comment: Please post a minimal example illustrating the problem.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph It's a big project, I can't post it even if I wanted it. If I move the offending code to the first source file, it works fine.. just from the second one not and I can't understand why. Can push_back fail with that assert for sure ?

Comment: It's not a type mistake, I am sure of that. Just consider all the common pitfalls out.. what can the problem be then ? Identical code, doesn't work just from one source.. deq is global.

Comment: Is the code multi-threaded? Are you blowing your stack? Are you running out of memory? Catch the exception and watch what error you get. Else i can just say: This thread is worthless without code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you have moved the `deq.push_back(object)` statement to within a loop and thus modifying the container invalidates the loop iterator?

Comment: Yes! I'm sure this is it. I was just reading about it on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/push_back. Sorry to the guys above, I can't believe I'm such a newb with STL. I think I zeroed in on the offending location, how do I revalidate ?

Comment: You need a small redesign which avoids modifying the collection during the loop.